# error in connecting to aws service

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to AWS instance and getting the following error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/18AB-992F$ ssh -i shantanuo.pem abc.compute-1.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'abc.compute-1.amazonaws.com (107.22.129.243)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 0d:f0:ab:53:bb:fc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'abc.compute-1.amazonaws.com,107.22.129.243' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'shantanuo.pem' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: shantanuo.pem
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I am not able to change the permission of the file because I am using Ubuntu Live CD.
Is the file permission of "shantanuo.pem" the only issue?

Comment: The file permissions are definitively an issue. I had several time this error and it got fix by changing the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change **pem** file permissions to `400`.